# Check file PDF or image before upload

Tags: php, image, file, pdf, upload

I am studying PHP but I don't get the right way by myself. I'd like having Img always required (and I check this in the form input `required` attribute) but I can decide if upload PDF or not. The script doesn't continue if I don't select both.

I have this:

```
    // image select from form
    $img = basename($_FILES['img']['name']);
    $allow_img = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg');
    $ext_img = explode('.', strtolower($_FILES['img']['name']));
    $type_img= end($ext_img);

    //pdf select from form
    $pdf = basename($_FILES['pdf']['name']);
    $allow_pdf = array('pdf');
    $ext_pdf = explode('.', strtolower($_FILES['pdf']['name']));
    $type_pdf= end($ext_pdf);

    if ($img || $pdf) {
        if(!in_array($type_img, $allow_img) || !in_array($type_pdf, $allow_pdf) ) {
         echo "<p><a href='../admin.php'><img style='border:none;' src='../../img/arrow-left.png' /></a>Only jpg, png, jpeg and PDF.</p>";       
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Please also post the corresponsing HTML markup by editing the question using the `edit` button above.

Comment: Oh, and what does this mean: "The script doesn't continue"?

Comment: doesn't continue mean that if I don't select img and pdf It's not loaded on mysql but I want only check if files are jpg, pdf etc...if users don't want to upload img or pdf I want the script always continue loading on mysql the others part of the form I didn't post beacause the problem is only with this upload

Comment: I repeat my question, since you did not really answer it: what does "doesn't continue" mean? You see, scripts do not simply stop. There always is a reason if they do. And that reason is either they are termianted by a command (which is not the case here) or something crashed. In that case there _always_ is some error in the http servers error log. This entry is what answers your question.  so if I ask "what does that mean" then I ask: "what is actually happening? Take a look at the log file ans see what is going on!". There is no sense in _guessing_! Take a look and see instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go a super fast way to accomplish this:

```
$filename = $_FILES['img']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// allowed extensions
$allowed = array('jpeg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'gif');

if (in_array($ext, $allowed)) {
    echo "<p><a href='../admin.php'><img style='border:none;' src='../../img/arrow-left.png' /></a>Only jpg, png, jpeg and PDF.</p>";       
}
```

That's it :)

Answer (score 0):

You need javascript for this.

Before you send return, you have check type of file.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the second `basename()` call crashes, since no `$_FILES['pdf']` is present when no pdf file is uploaded. But you don't even check for an error here... Take a look into the http servers error log file, most likely you will see the error there.

That said: *always* look into the log files if something unexpected happens. And always test for a variables existance before you use it. And always do error checking when calling some function which might not return what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pathinfo()` inbuilt php function,

```
 $File = $_FILES['image']['name'];
 $Infos = pathinfo($File);
 echo $extension = $info[extension];

 echo "<pre>"; print_r($Infos); echo "</pre>";
 $extension = strtolower( $extension);
 if( $extension=='pdf'){
    // do your stuff
 }
```

Comment: thx phpinfo() is much better!! but how can I allow users to decide to not unpload img or pdf? if php checks extensions the upload on mysql of the others form part form (name, job etc etc..)